# Como mapear o Relacionamento com a classe base em Table per Type (TPT)

Tags: entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada entidade nessa hierarquia tem sua tabela. Mas, agora preciso cadastrar uma Pessoa com uma Cidade onde ela mora.

Como mapear para eu consiga gravar uma Cidade em uma Pessoa?

Classe Pessoa

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Cidade

```
public class Cidade
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Pessoa Física

```
public class PessoaFisica: Pessoa
{
    ...
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Pessoa Jurídica

```
public class PessoaJuridica: Pessoa
{
    ...
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento Pessoa:

```
public class PessoaConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    ...
    //table
    ToTable("pessoa");

    //relationships
    //CIDADE???
}
```

Mapeamento Cidade:

```
public class CidadeConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
    {
        public CidadeConfiguracao()
        {
            //Key
            HasKey(c => c.Id);

            //fields
            Property(c => c.Nome).HasColumnName("Nome").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();

            //table
            ToTable("cidade");

            //relationship
            HasRequired<Estado>(s => s.Estado)
                .WithMany(s => s.Cidades).HasForeignKey(s => s.IdEstado);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mapear o relacionamento da classe base Pessoa com Cidade de forma que as classes derivadas PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica possam ser gravadas com suas respectivas cidades foi necessário adicionar uma propriedade de coleção/lista de pessoas na classe Cidade:

```
public class Cidade
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}
```

Depois, alterar o mapeamento de Pessoa:

```
public class PessoaConfiguracao: EntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    ...
    //table
    ToTable("pessoa");

    //relationships
    HasRequired(p => p.Cidade).WithMany(p => p.Pessoas).Map(m => m.MapKey("CidadeId"));
}
```